# Will this modal Microsoft EULA popup on my web-server?

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog, eula

i was debugging a line of code:

```
SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(cs.ProviderName, cs.ConnectionString, selectCommand);
```

and a Microsoft EULA dialog box popped up:

[image]

After declining it, i ended up debugging *something*:

[image]

i don't mind accepting EULA's i won't abide by, but i'm concerned that the modal dialog will popup, and stop, my ASP.net web-server.

Will this modal Microsoft EULA popup on my web-server? Is Microsoft guaranteed to have architected their *"accept on demand"* license agreements so they will not try to show a GUI dialog if it's not running on an interactive session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *debugger* popup, caused by stepping into the reference source.
Declining it will show you disassembly instead of the original Microsoft source code.

If you install Visual Studio and run the debugger on your server, it will pop up.

Comment: Normally i've been developing against .NET 3.5, and Microsoft's been refusing to provide the reference source for that (as [this question and....you!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095769/how-can-we-get-microsoft-to-maintain-the-net-reference-source) found out). .NET 4.0 looks to have reference source. (also [reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139269/vs2010-how-to-enable-enable-net-framework-source-stepping))